# Ant: Consecutive xmlproperty returning values from the first file

Tags: xml, ant, build

In my ant build.xml file, I reading two different xml files and I am accessing the same property in file. I am getting the first value read for both.

```
<target name="readport">
    <xmlproperty file"${port.file}" collapseattribute="true"/>
    <property name="portversion" value="${xs:schema.version}"/>
</target>
<target name="readname">
    <xmlproperty file"${name.file}" collapseattribute="true"/>
    <property name="nameversion" value="${xs:schema.version}"/>
</target>
```

In other words, after running the second target, I am getting the value from the first xml file.
Is there a way to clear first xml read?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you running both targets together or separately? Properties in Ant are immutable.

Comment: I am running both target separately: another target is dependent of them

Comment: So you have another target that depends on both of them? If they're both being executed as dependencies in the same run, they will share their properties. Could you post your entire ant script (or at least all of the targets that are being executed) along with the command you're using?